# What is the ~/Applications directory for?

Tags: macos, applications, big-sur

I was asked by tech support to run the command `ls -l ~/Applications` and found the directory (`/Users/<me>/Applications`) to be empty. All my applications seem to actually be in `/Applications`.
I'm not very familiar with the Mac file-system; is this normal? Why do I have two applications directories anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `Applications` directory in your user's home directory is not a standard directory, but some users create and use them. If you have it, either you, someone else, or some script created it.

In older versions of macOS, it usually does not matter much where you store your app; they are location independent. It often even happened (and still happens) that users downloaded disk images (`.dmg`) and ran the contained applications from that image, not being aware that the app is not stored in a "normal" volume. So instead of copying an app to `/Applications` (which requires administrator privileges and makes the app available to all users on the system), some users prefer or preferred to store their apps in a folder in their home directory. A natural choice for that is to create an `Applications` folder.

Nowadays, some OS restrictions may require you to store the app in `/Applications`. App Store managed apps live there, and apps that have a System Extension must also be stored there (or else the System Extension cannot get activated; the reasons for that are a bit complicated and relate to the OS' need to manage the System Extensions and keep track of their "parent" apps).

Comment: I believe the Zoom installer puts its app in ~/Applications if you tell it to install for "this user only". The Thonny app for Python development also puts itself in ~/Applications.

Comment: It's a little weird that ~/Applications would get created, but no actual application get installed into it. Maybe there was an app there once, but it got deleted/uninstalled?

Comment: ~/Applications is a standard place - all apps that you install for "this user only" which is an option on many installers would be there

Answer (score -3):

Each user account has its own Library folder (which includes the Applications folder), in addition to accessing the machine-wide Library folder. Software installed by an administrator is available to all user accounts from the machine-wide Library folder. However, software installed by users (assuming they can get admin authentication to do so) will be installed in the user-specific Library folder. This means that software with a one-user licence can be installed for that user but it will not be available to other (unlicensed) users.

Comment: ~/Application is not in ~/Library